# How to do "runAction" step by step in sprite kit framework?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

There are two actions to run, one is move the object from pointA to pointB, the other is move the object from pointB to pointC. But when I execute them soon enough, the object will move from pointA to pointC directly.

```
beed.sprite1.position = A

let moveA = SKAction.moveTo(B, duration: 0.2)
beed.sprite1.runAction(moveA)

let moveB = SKAction.moveTo(C, duration: 0.2)
beed.sprite1.runAction(moveB)
```

It seems a interesting feature in sprite kit. What should I do so I can execute them step by step, that is, move the object from pointA to pointB, THEN, move it from pointB to pointC?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? It's driving me mad, as for me also, combining the actions into one sequence is not an option. I also have to execute them step by step - even under user single-step control.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the actions to an SKAction Sequence would probably be your best bet.

```
beed.sprite1.position = A
let moveSequence = SKAction.sequence([
SKAction.moveTo(B, duration: 0.2),
SKAction.moveTo(C, duration: 0.2)])
beed.sprite1.runAction(moveSequence)
```

Comment: One more related question, what if I have action sequences which is created at different time and I want to execute them sequentially?

Comment: @AllenLin Your question makes no sense at all.

Comment: @AllenLin Yes, but it just sounds like the question in the OP.

Comment: This is very belated but his question makes perfect sense - and I'm facing the same situation: the actions may be discrete in that other things happen in between, even user input. Combining the actions into one sequence is not an option.